# Google Geolocation Api to track users Location - COuntry, City, State, Timezone

Tags: geolocation, geoip, freegeoip

Does google offer geo location ip services like freegeoip, maxmind etc which can offer me the users exact ( need almost accurate like how gooogle offers) location, Country - State - City, Timezone, 
Brower used
Mobile or PC

Answer (score 0):

Google offers it as service of HTML5 in web browsers. You will need to have users permission to retrieve their geolocation information. The web browser will prompt for permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the best accuracy for mobile users you should use the navigator geolocation API (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) and enable high accuracy to get the exact GPS position.

A good practice if your app can benefit from a less accurate location instead of no location at all is to fall back to an external IP geolocation API when the user denies location access : https://db-ip.com/api/jsdoc.php#browsergeo